# How to increase accuracy of my CNN making Handwritten Digit Recogniser

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

Here Is my Code:
i can't improve my accuracy i only get 10% accuracy by this. Someone can tell me which activation function or something i should choose so i can increase my accuracy.

```
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Convolution2D 
    from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
    from keras.layers import Flatten
    from keras.layers import Dense
```

initializing the cnn

```
    classifier  = Sequential()
```

step 1

```
    classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3 ,3 , input_shape = (64,64,3) , 
    activation = 'relu'))


    #step 2 pooling

    classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
```

flattening

```
    classifier.add(Flatten())


    classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 64, activation = 'softmax'))



    classifier.add(Dense(output_dim =10, activation = 'softmax'))

    classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam' , loss = 'categorical_crossentropy'                 
    , metrics = ['accuracy'] )

    from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=90, 
             width_shift_range=0.1, height_shift_range=0.1, 
             horizontal_flip=True)


    training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('numbers/',
                                             target_size = (64, 64),
                                             batch_size = 64,
                                             class_mode = 'categorical')

    classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                     samples_per_epoch = 2000,
                     nb_epoch = 25)
```

Comment: For starters, replace the `softmax` activation of your hidden dense layer with `relu`; in general, why not starting from the [Keras MNIST example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py) and building up from there?

Comment: It would also help to have an idea of the kinds of digits you're using.  It looks like you aren't using a pre-existing dataset from Keras, such as the MNIST example that @desertnaut alluded to.  Depending on how complex your digits are, you may need to add several more conv layers before going to fully-connected for the classification.

Comment: @rayryeng it is unclear indeed - a clarification would be useful

Comment: I think you have a problem with your optimizer. Just imagine you have a training batch and update using gradient descent. I think, you end up overfitting for this batch and do random guess for all other samples. I guess you have 10 classes right? So the 10% are just random guessing. Try to play with the parameters of your optimizer.